# Bulk import Product Bundles – WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, wpallimport

I’ve installed the plugin **Woocommerce – Product bundles**

As I am working in a shoe company and my boss needs to setup some pack of shoes (pack of **some product variations**).

I found a way to do that with this plugin but.. is there **any way to bulk import product?**

I’m setting up a website in which the product bundle plugin is required.
Due to the very large amount of bundled products to setup along with the very large amount of variable product to link to them, I would like to know

1. if there is any way to csv bulk link variable products to a bundle product and
2. if there is a way to bulk csv import bundled products as well.

I really would be grateful if anyone got any answer/tricks.

Thanks.

PS: I went around almost all of [these plugins](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/group-bundle-products-woocommerce/?_ga=1.75509904.401037340.1476240412) without any way to figure it out.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution with the plugin **WP All Import Pro**, there is a **Custom Field** created by the plugin called "**_bundle_data**".

So during the import we have to setup this Custom field in Step 3 under the tabs **Custom Fields**.

*Name:* _bundle_data

*Value:* {_bundle_data[1]} *: drag and drop your correlated field.*

Hope that helps. :)

Comment: Woocommerce – Product bundles has been updated and modify this feature.

Now bundles items stored in this tables:

wp_woocommerce_bundled_items
wp_woocommerce_bundled_itemmeta